Intuition around diagonalization of symmetric matrices
For $A$ symmetric, we have $A=Q \Lambda Q^T$ where $Q^TQ=I$. This translates to: action of $A$ is equivalent to rotating, then scaling, then rotating back. But if we are first rotating, then rotating back, why do they not cancel out, and we only do scaling? What is it about these two operations that makes them not exactly inverses of each other?

It is just scaling, but in the directions of the eigenvectors and  not in the directions of the standard basis.

This would only be true if you scaled each basis vector by the same amount, in other words, Λ = $\lambda$I$_n$, as P$\lambda$I$_n$P$^T$ = PP$^T$$\lambda$I$_n$ = $\lambda$I$_n$
However, if Λ was $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$ then for example
\begin{align}
A &= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\\ A &= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\\ A &= \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
which is not the same as Λ.
